# Is there a way to make highcharts tick lines point inwards rather than outwards

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I wanted to know if it is possible to make highcharts tick lines point inwards rather than outwards? I didn't see any obvious setting in the API.

But this is quite typical in scientific plots.

[image]

So I would like that the tick markers should go upwards instead of downwards?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by setting `xAxis.tickPosition = 'inside'`:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
    tickPosition: 'inside'
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      439,
      525,
      571,
      696,
      970,
      119,
      137,
      154
    ]
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8earkyLp/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPosition